# Wordpress is sending an email after using wp_insert_user

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some issues with this method:

```
$WP_array = array(
                'user_login'            =>  "info here",
                'user_email'            =>  "info here",
                'user_pass'             =>  "info here",
                'first_name'            =>  "info here",
                'last_name'             =>  "info here",
                'role'                  =>  "info here",
                'show_admin_bar_front'  =>  "info here",
            ) ;

            $user_id = wp_insert_user($WP_array);
```

After inserting my new user, my new user received an empty email from wordpress D: so how can I prevent sending emails to my user,

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

wp_insert_user() fires the function user_register() just after the user is created. which triggers wp_new_user_notification() to send notification. you will need to hook `wp_new_user_notification` function to prevent sending email
you can do it like below:

```
add_action( 'register_new_user', function(){
    remove_action( 'register_new_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications' );
}, 9);
```